# How to get all parents (up to root) nodes for selected in TreeView control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, hierarchy

If I have a TreeView (myTreeview),how can I obtain a list of all parent nodes (parent, parents of parents ect.) of selected node?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd recomended you to create a set of your own tree helpers, for example, next one is for your problem:

```
    public static class TreeHelpers
    {
        public static IEnumerable<TItem> GetAncestors<TItem>(TItem item, Func<TItem, TItem> getParentFunc)
        {
            if (getParentFunc == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("getParentFunc");
            }
            if (ReferenceEquals(item, null)) yield break;
            for (TItem curItem = getParentFunc(item); !ReferenceEquals(curItem, null); curItem = getParentFunc(curItem))
            {
                yield return curItem;
            }
        }

        //TODO: Add other methods, for example for 'prefix' children recurence enumeration
    }
```

And example of usage (in your context):

```
        IList<TreeNode> ancestorList = TreeHelpers.GetAncestors(node, x => x.Parent).ToList();
```

Why is this better than using list<>.Add()? - because we can use lazy LINQ functions, such as .FirstOrDefault(x => ...)

P.S. to include 'current' item into result enumerable, use `TItem curItem = item`, instead of `TItem curItem = getParentFunc(item)`

Answer (score 3):

If you want the actual objects, use the [TreeNode.Parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.parent.aspx) property recursively until you reach the root. Something like:

```
private void GetPathToRoot(TreeNode node, List<TreeNode> path)
{
    if(node == null) return; // previous node was the root.
    else
    {
        path.add(node);
        GetPathToRoot(node.Parent, path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! it was very useful. The recursive methods are very recursive;)

Answer (score 1):

Alexander Mavrinsky's answer is really useful, but my approach has many changes. My code is shorter and clearer not only in the method, but also in the call sites (by specifying his generics).

```cs
public static class TreeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TreeNode> GetAncestors(this TreeNode node)
    {
        if (node == null)
            yield break;
        while ((node = node.Parent) != null)
            yield return node;
    }
}
```

For instance: `var firstCheckedAncestor = treeNode.GetAncestors().First(x => x.Checked);`

Or if you really need every parent node: `var allAncestors = treeNode.GetAncestors().ToList();`

---

But if you plan to have more than one class using the same logic, here is the generic method and a couple of extensions for each class (so you can keep the simpler API on each caller):

```cs
public static IEnumerable<T> GetAncestors<T>(T item, Func<T, T> getParent)
{
    if (item == null)
        yield break;
    while ((item = getParent(item)) != null)
        yield return item;
}
public static IEnumerable<TreeNode> GetAncestors(this TreeNode node) => GetAncestors(node, x => x.Parent);
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAncestors(this Control control) => GetAncestors(control, x => x.Parent);
```

Answer (score -2):

I Think you need to take an Array of Nodes

```
List<TreeNode> resultNodes = new List<TreeNode>()
private void GetNodesToRoot(TreeNode node)
{
    if(node == null) return; // previous node was the root.
    else
    {
        resultNodes.add(node);
        GetNodesToRoot(node.Parent);
    }
}
```

Comment: hey no offense...i just meant u dont need the second parameter